# What kind of graphs are these and how can I create equations that model them?

Tags: graphing-functions

Think of a line graph where the line stays somewhat flat and low to the ground for a while (but still upsloping, nondecreasing) and then starts to arc up.

I'm trying to figure out a way to "characterize" these kinds of lines (when does this "hard arc" point occur, how hard is the arc, etc). Please ask questions if I am not being clear.

I tried to draw an example of what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7HWe.png

For example I should be able to have a model equation that describes a line like this, and based on whatever such coefficient I can say "This coefficient means the arc starts to occur sooner" or "This coefficient means the arc, when it occurs, is rather strong." Does this make sense?

Comment: These look like exponential functions? That is, functions of the form $f(x) = Ae^{bx}$. In particular since they increase left to right, $b > 0$ and the higher the $b$, the quicker they "arc" up.

Comment: What would A, b, x, c represent here?

Comment: A,b > 0 real numbers and x and c are any reals.

Comment: Y=f(x) which u plot on curve

Comment: I mean what do they affect on the graph itself (i.e. a high/low A changes this, high/low b changes this, etc)

Comment: Double bass, I recommend playing with wolfram alpha and seeing how each of the parameters @Suugaku mentioned change the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

These are graphs of $e^x$. You can see at x=0 the graph starts raising  and after 10 it's just increases drastically like a vertical line.

So, for $Ae^{x-c}$ the graph will start shooting upwards at $x-c=0$
C shifts graph from one place to other on X-axis.

and the A controls the amplitude of the function and B controls the argument of function $f(x)$ , so it can even reverse the whole curve too (b<0).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/  Enter any function here and see every here and there of it.